# How to set click event to a button in codebehind in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, events, vba

I want to bind an event to a button in runtime using Excel VBA. Is there a method to create it like `button.Click += button_Click` in C#?

Comment: You need to clarify just what you are asking for. Are you trying to dynamically change what subroutine that a button launches? If so, is it a forms button or an active-X button?

Answer (score 0):

This routine adds a button and a button click event at run time to a already existing Userform1.  Note you need to set a reference to Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3 (Tools | References)

```
Sub AddControlDynamically()

Dim vbCompFrm As VBComponent
Dim objButton As Object

'Edit "Userform1" in the following line to your Userform name
Set vbCompFrm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Userform1")

'Following line creates a command button on the form
Set objButton = vbCompFrm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")

With objButton
    .Name = "cmdButton1"   'Can use this name for the Add event sub
    .Left = 10
    .Top = 10
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 80
    .Caption = "My Button"
End With

With vbCompFrm.CodeModule
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, "Private Sub cmdButton1_Click()"
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, "    MsgBox ""Hello World!"""
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, "End Sub"
End With

End Sub
```